# Using Tailwind classes in React, why is the color of my text not changing as expected?

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx, tailwind-css, template-literals

I want the color of the text to be all different and based on the color inside the array colors[] by using map function and template literal.

```
const title = "Hello".split("");
const colors = [
  "#8145f6",
  "#188ae0",
  "#f3b92a",
  "#f93669",
  "#5fb84e",
];

<motion.div className="">
      {title.map((letter, index) => {
        return (
          <motion.span
            className={`text-5xl text-[${colors[index]}]`}
            key={index}
          >
            {letter}
          </motion.span>
        );
      })}
</motion.div>
```

I'm pretty sure that the syntax is already correct since it's showing properly in inspect (for the tailwind syntax) and if I replace the ${colors[index]} with just #8145f6 it worked, but with the mapping I'm still in the blue of why it won't work.

Any suggestions/alternatives/critics will be appreciated! Sorry beforehand if there's a mistake in my question format as I'm still new to asking questions Thank you for your time!

P.S: I tried `:nth-child()` selector, Thank you Ryan for the suggestion, it gives the desired result! But is there still a way to make it more dynamic and uses something like the mapping function or something else that makes it more '*automatic*' or with lesser lines of code? Once again really appreciate the suggestion thank you!

Comment: Have you considered using pure CSS? Example: test-5xl:nth-child(2) { background: #188ae0; }}